# How does a community or field, generally accept a paper in academia?

Tags: publications, research-process, paper-submission, proofreading

I'll just rephrase what I had said in the comments, as I believe it summaries the question better, and to whoever downvoted ( assuming because of how "complicated" what I said was ) I hope this suffices:

There exists proof methods, particularly so whatever a claim may be, an undeniable truth arises from a well executed proof, and when the proof methods are carried out, you may arrive at a result that satisfies the claim therefore, but the problem in question may have another given in the claim that is unknown, or unapparent. How would one know there isn't some unknown or unapparent fact also applied to the claim. How would this effect a paper being published, and if this is fact, what would this say about how the community treats papers generally?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you are asking. Maybe an example would help?

Comment: Ok, I will state that in my question.

Comment: I think it will be better if you are more precise; if you narrow down your question to your particular field of interest.

Comment: I would have done that, but since its academia, and not say, mathematics, I don't want to get banned off or something along those lines. To be fair, I did provide an example.

Comment: *I did provide an example* --- A more carefully written example would help. For example, "the curvature of the moon is anything other than say, a line" seems to suggest that one answer to the the question "what is the curvature of the moon" is "a line", which is a category mistake. Probably you mean "the curvature of the moon is anything other than the curvature of a line", which could be better expressed as "the curvature of the moon is not zero". This is only one of many awkward or not-quite-correct wordings in what you've written that collectively makes your message extremely opaque.

Comment: Your right, Dave L Renfro. I noticed that mistake before, and failed to edit, as I figured it would be overlooked both ways, and figured it may not necessarily affect what the question was in the first place, anyways. But yes. If you could do anything to help me understand what more, is exactly hard to understand, I'll edit them. Starting with that one.

Comment: If I understand correctly, a more concrete way to put the question may be: "How does the community deal with a theory that may be correct but cannot be proven?" And a good example may be the situational in physics particle theory -- there are tons of papers that posit ideas (e.g., higgsino models in the MSSM); these models might be true, and certainly would address many open questions if so, but there is not yet proof either way.

Comment: But there exists proof methods, and when the proof methods are carried out, you may arrive at a result that satisfies the claim, but the problem in question may have another given in the claim that is unknown, or unapparent. You see the problem with what you said, is it would surely imply all papers are of such nature. Is this truly the case? How would one know there isn't some unknown or unapparent fact also applied to the claim. With reference to the example, if light was unknown to us, how would we know to factor it in with the curvature of the moon.

Comment: I appreciate that you've taken some effort to clarify the question, but it's still not clear what sort of answers you are looking for, unfortunately. Some of the "big questions" you raise would require a textbook about metaphysics or epistomology to answer (which is not our role). If there is a more immediate question about how the world of research handles uncertainty "in real life", it is not clear to me.

Comment: Then, could you at least say, if true, the way the research community handles such things, can only be described by epistemology, and no explanation could be given otherwise, such that it would fully go beyond the bounds of just simply keeping the bounds of the answer within academia and that alone; if so, can you please guarantee, or otherwise, answer that question. Or at the very least, simplify it ( if possible ) to bounds academia will allow.

Comment: These are all questions not answered to me, just "no, this is not relevant" without explanation, which is the sole most crucial thing in a response if you ask me. Either that, or I can provide explicit evidence of events where often, the answer in question, is in truth, blatantly ignoring points made in the question so as to act in a condescending manner.

Comment: I think its reasonable to be able to explain that when you research for a paper, with the purpose or great likelihood someone will use it, to apply it. And if you don't even know when its applicable... and if your literally the person researching, your telling me you don't care? To be frank, its becoming increasingly more cryptic when you do care and when you don't, because you certainly care enough to prove everything, just to a point where you can't can't explain everything.

Comment: And if you can't explain everything, this clearly shows you don't even care about thinking about that. Instead, when I do ask for a question on this site, I instead get an answer that completely ignores the forefront of the question that I had asked, the actual meat of the question.

Comment: I am trying to understand your question: You are worried that there are unknowns that might invalidate a theory, and you want to know what science does about that. Unknowns are, by definition, not known, which limits what you can do about them. So what we do about that is that we never accept a theory as true. We consider some theories more plausible than others on various good and less good grounds.

Comment: I interpret your question as follows. Is it accurate? "When researchers study a system, one method is to build a mathematical model for it and prove that it has various properties. Then the real system should have those properties as well. But a model is never 100% accurate because of extra assumptions and simplifications, which might even be implicit and unnoticed, so the results don't match reality. How do researchers take this into account when writing and reviewing papers?"

Comment: Maarten Buis, thank you.

Comment: IIkka Torma, I would say that is an example. I don't suppose that example could not be generalizable ( in this case, your describing a system, say a physical system ). So under those terms, I would say you are correct, and if you could apply that to academia ( the question itself ) and report what written or unwritten rules permit the community to achieve conclusions by working around such uncertainty, I would consider that a clear, and great answer.

Comment: @cag51: *"How does the community deal with a theory that may be correct but cannot be proven?"* --- This issue arose in a physics Ph.D. defense I attended in February 1980. (I have a copy of the department notice for it—why I know the date—that was advertised on the math/physics department bulletin boards for anyone interested to attend.) A complaint that was raised (by [this person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugen_Merzbacher), I believe) that the theory as yet did not include interacting particles, and thus was not even theoretically experimentally verifiable. **(continued)**

Comment: Dave L Renfro, so far, I would consider this the best answer, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll restrict this answer to the field(s) of pure mathematics and similar things. For other fields the standard will be very different, say philosophy or psychology.

First, math has a clear standard of proof and truth. To be true, in the modern conception held by most mathematicians, something has to be derivable from a set of axioms using well determined logical rules. But the chain of proof can be very long, depending on other things "held" to be true and previously proven. Some of the chains began in ancient times. Many others about a hundred or so years ago when axiomatic mathematics came to the fore.

Second, people make mistakes. The chains of proof can be long. They can also be very twisty and when there are many levels of abstraction in a proof it isn't terribly difficult to make an error. Sometimes a mistake is made because someone has an "insight" into a problem that is very subtly wrong, but seems right. This might cause them to gloss over difficulties. Others with the same background might make the same error. It might be effectively impossible to check the complete chain of proof, due to its length.

Moreover, prior to the axiomatization of math, the standard was quite different. Sometimes verification depended to some extend on applications of theory. Some of that was re-established axiomatically, but there is a huge body of "knowledge".

Third, the work of mathematicians, if sufficiently important, is checked by other mathematicians, who are, themselves, skilled, but not perfect. Not all errors are caught in the publication review process, even though papers are normally reviewed by a few independent mathematicians with skill in the particular field. Not all errors slip through, but a few do. And generally, the "checkers" are happy to show their work, explaining why they accept (or not) the proofs in a given paper.

Fourth, we normally trust the experts, but also generally maintain a wee bit of skepticism generally, knowing the history of long lived errors.

So, for a direct answer to the question, if a paper has passed review it is likely, but not necessarily, accepted by the mob. But "completely accept" is possible for simple results that have stood the test of time. Complex results and complex arguments, not so much. I once found an error by an important mathematician that had been in place for more than 50 years. It was buried deep in a complex proof but was, in its nature, somewhat elementary.

The wee bit of skepticism often leads professors to have their doctoral students examine the reasoning in old papers (just as I was) to verify them. The verification doesn't add much to the mathematics unless and error is found, but it can add immensely to the insight and understanding of the student.

So, the [answer of Anonymous Physicist](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/173010/75368) is not incorrect at all, though it lacks detail.

"Trust but verify" is the standard.

What you do about it is verify in any case that is vitally important to you. But generally trust what other mathematicians, perhaps with more experience, have concluded.

---

In math there are four possible outcomes for a statement. True, if it can be proven (derived from axioms). False, if a counterexample can be found. Unknown if we have neither a proof nor a contradiction. Unknowable, since axiom systems [can't be both complete and consistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems).

---

Caveat. I have a certain [philosophy of mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_mathematics) that a few others don't hold. My philosophy leads me to think in a certain way and do mathematics in a certain way. It is pretty widely held, but not universal. Others with a different outlook might just pop in with a rather different answer.

Comment: For what its worth ( lot of dislikes on my question ), this answer appropriately answered my question. Also, I would like to say, that maybe this would be something easy to think about for most people- granted, they actually were studying academia, and not just someone like me- who are hoping to at a later point i.e not people who are ignorant to the subject itself. I believe it would have been hard to answer otherwise, hence the relevancy of the question.

Comment: Somehow, at the end of it all, I did manage an answer that satisfied me entirely, and I'm not sure what that is to say about the ambiguity or general unclearness of my question, that many seem to say without actual reasoning. Thanks again, Buffy.

Answer (score 10):

I think your question is:

> How do academics become completely sure that a paper is correct?

And the answer is that normally they do not.

Comment: Let us avoid arguments in the comments. Mike: I understand this answer may not be what you're looking for, but other answers may come.